# whatsmeow get live location from sender

Tags: go, whatsapp

I'm using whatsmeow from golang package https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow

I try the example and run without problem, but I'm curious, is there a way to get sender's live location from the message??

this is my log :

```
    05:57:27.711 [Client/Recv DEBUG] <message from="6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net" id="974EEAED36D9D7B9354CF31D78BBE2A8" notify="Rolly Maulana Awangga" t="1663801047" type="media"><enc duration="3599" mediatype="livelocation" type="pkmsg" v="2"><!-- 3415 bytes --></enc></message>
    05:57:27.712 [Client DEBUG] Decrypting 1 messages from 6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net
    05:57:27.712 [Client/Send DEBUG] <ack class="message" id="974EEAED36D9D7B9354CF31D78BBE2A8" to="6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net"/>
    GetConversation :  
    Sender :  6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net
    Sender Number :  6281312000300
    IsGroup :  false
    MessageSource :  {6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net 6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net false false }
    ID :  974EEAED36D9D7B9354CF31D78BBE2A8
    PushName :  Rolly Maulana Awangga
    BroadcastListOwner :
    Category :
    Chat :  6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net
    DeviceSentMeta :  <nil>
    IsFromMe :  false
    MediaType :  livelocation
    Multicast :  false
    Info.Chat.Server :  s.whatsapp.net
    05:57:27.773 [Client/Send DEBUG] <receipt id="974EEAED36D9D7B9354CF31D78BBE2A8" to="6281312000300@s.whatsapp.net" type="inactive"/>
```

The sender sends the live location to the receiver. the receiver can look up Medyatype is livelocation from whatsmeow go package. so there is a way to get the live location coordinate?
and this is my code :

```
    package main

    import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "os/signal"
        "syscall"

        _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"

        "go.mau.fi/whatsmeow"
        "go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/store/sqlstore"
        "go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/types/events"
        waLog "go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/util/log"
    )

    var client *whatsmeow.Client

    func eventHandler(evt interface{}) {
        switch v := evt.(type) {
        case *events.Message:
            if !v.Info.IsFromMe {
                fmt.Println("GetConversation : ", v.Message.GetConversation())
                fmt.Println("Sender : ", v.Info.Sender)
                fmt.Println("Sender Number : ", v.Info.Sender.User)
                fmt.Println("IsGroup : ", v.Info.IsGroup)
                fmt.Println("MessageSource : ", v.Info.MessageSource)
                fmt.Println("ID : ", v.Info.ID)
                fmt.Println("PushName : ", v.Info.PushName)
                fmt.Println("BroadcastListOwner : ", v.Info.BroadcastListOwner)
                fmt.Println("Category : ", v.Info.Category)
                fmt.Println("Chat : ", v.Info.Chat)
                fmt.Println("DeviceSentMeta : ", v.Info.DeviceSentMeta)
                fmt.Println("IsFromMe : ", v.Info.IsFromMe)
                fmt.Println("MediaType : ", v.Info.MediaType)
                fmt.Println("Multicast : ", v.Info.Multicast)
                fmt.Println("Info.Chat.Server : ", v.Info.Chat.Server)
                if v.Info.Chat.Server == "g.us" {
                    groupInfo, err := client.GetGroupInfo(v.Info.Chat)
                    fmt.Println("error GetGroupInfo : ", err)
                    fmt.Println("Nama Group : ", groupInfo.GroupName.Name)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func main() {
        dbLog := waLog.Stdout("Database", "DEBUG", true)
        // Make sure you add appropriate DB connector imports, e.g. github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 for SQLite
        container, err := sqlstore.New("sqlite3", "file:gowa.db?_foreign_keys=on", dbLog)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        // If you want multiple sessions, remember their JIDs and use .GetDevice(jid) or .GetAllDevices() instead.
        deviceStore, err := container.GetFirstDevice()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        clientLog := waLog.Stdout("Client", "DEBUG", true)
        client = whatsmeow.NewClient(deviceStore, clientLog)
        client.AddEventHandler(eventHandler)

        if client.Store.ID == nil {
            // No ID stored, new login
            qrChan, _ := client.GetQRChannel(context.Background())
            err = client.Connect()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            for evt := range qrChan {
                if evt.Event == "code" {
                    // Render the QR code here
                    // e.g. qrterminal.GenerateHalfBlock(evt.Code, qrterminal.L, os.Stdout)
                    // or just manually `echo 2@... | qrencode -t ansiutf8` in a terminal
                    fmt.Println("QR code:", evt.Code)
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("Login event:", evt.Event)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Already logged in, just connect
            err = client.Connect()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }

        // Listen to Ctrl+C (you can also do something else that prevents the program from exiting)
        c := make(chan os.Signal)
        signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
        <-c

        client.Disconnect()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual data of the message in a `go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/types/events.Message` is in a field called [`Message`](https://github.com/tulir/whatsmeow/blob/5c8577b8ac6f718e809e4c06dcc1e9260cc7c73d/types/events/events.go#L214), which is of type `go.mau.fi/whatsmeow/types/binary/proto.Message`.

That is a generated Go struct, generated by the protobuf compiler.
The struct has fields for each type of message.
If the mediatype of the event is "livelocation", then you should expect the livelocation data to be in [`v.Message.LiveLocationMessage`](https://github.com/tulir/whatsmeow/blob/5c8577b8ac6f718e809e4c06dcc1e9260cc7c73d/binary/proto/def.pb.go#L9052)

Comment: so how to get value from proto variabel?

Comment: It seems you've already figured it out (seeing the "answer" that you posted, v.Message.LiveLocationMessage.DegreesLatitude). There is nothing special about protobufs - once the Go code is generated from the .proto file, it becomes normal go code with structs and fields and receiver methods.

Comment: I don't get it, why do I get 0xc000b02990 instead of getting real latitude from v.Message.LiveLocationMessage.DegreesLatitude. so how to convert it into proper latitude format?

Answer (score 1):

big thanks. You save me time. this is actually I hope for

fmt.Println("livelocation : ", v.Message.LiveLocationMessage.DegreesLatitude)